# Is indefinite integral allowed if integrand has no real numbers in its domain

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently came across the integral:

$$
\int \sqrt{(x-3)}\Big[\arcsin(\ln x) + \arccos(\ln x)\Big]dx.
$$

It is easy to compute the integral without observing  domain of integrand and answer comes out as
$$
\frac{\pi}{3(x-3)^{(3/2)}} + C
$$ 
using $\arcsin(t) + \arccos(t)=\pi/2$.

So is it allowed to integrate like this or can I conclude that the function does not have any indefinite integral. Kindly help.

Comment: How are you defining integration with a function that has no domain?

Comment: usually for complex integrals especially in indefinate integrals we usually do not consider domain of integrand and apply some substitutions or properties which is what i did here.

Comment: I don't know who "we" refers to but it is not possible for any integral, definite or otherwise, to be performed without knowing that the integrand has a non-empty domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is defined at no point, then $\int f(x)\;dx$ cannot be computed.  But:

If $f$ has complex values, such as
$$
f(x) :=  \sqrt{(x-3)}\Big[\arcsin(\ln x) + \arccos(\ln x)\Big]
$$
then $\int f(x)\;dx$ can often be computed.  Of course you have to verify that $\arcsin(\ln x) + \arccos(\ln x) = \pi/2$ even for cases where the $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ are non-real (by looking up the definitions in that case).